# What is the gain of an isotropic antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, power, antennas, radio

My question is simple:

**What is the gain of an isotropic antenna in dBi?**

I cannot find a consistent answer on the internet. Some sources define it to be 0dBi and others define it to be 1dBi.

Thanks.

Comment: Where would gain come from?

Comment: suggest posting this on the amateur radio stack exchange. lots of antenna experts there, and they are nice guys.